# Как добавить в попап кнопку?

Tags: javascript, jquery

сейчас у меня из 4 кнопок отображается - три

[image: вторая иконка]
речь о второй иконке (автоплей), кликаем по ней - картинки сами листаются
использую https://www.lightgalleryjs.com/demos/thumbnails/

```js
 window.lightGallery(
          document.getElementById("thumbnails-gallery"),
          {
            autoplayFirstVideo: false,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayControls: true,
            counter: false,
            plugins: [lgZoom, lgThumbnail],
            download: true,
            controls: true,
           /* mobileSettings: {
              controls: false,
              showCloseIcon: false,
              download: false,
              rotate: false
            }*/
          }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Подключите файлы плагина Autoplay

   https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lightgallery@2.0.1/plugins/autoplay/lg-autoplay.min.js

   https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lightgallery@2.0.1/css/lg-autoplay.css
2. В конфиге пропишите название плагина `lgAutoplay` в массиве `plugins`.

---

```
window.lightGallery(
  document.getElementById("thumbnails-gallery"), {
    autoplayFirstVideo: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayControls: true,
    counter: false,
    plugins: [lgZoom, lgThumbnail, lgAutoplay], // <-- Сюда
    download: true,
    controls: true,
    /* mobileSettings: {
       controls: false,
       showCloseIcon: false,
       download: false,
       rotate: false
     }*/
  }
);
```

---

`autoplay: true` и `autoplayControls: true` в конфиге можно не прописывать, эти настройки по умолчанию включены.

Comment: спасибо огромное